# Высота блока в относительных величинах на MacOs

Tags: css, html, height, viewport

Есть сайт - лендинг. Один div высотой в 1 экран пользователя. Но проблема в том, что на маке относительные величины не работают, например height:90vh. Как обойти данную проблему?

Comment: С чего вы взяли что они не работают?

Comment: На маке относительные величины работают нормально. Проблемы нет, обходить ничего не нужно.

Comment: делаю 100 vh - Div больше, чем видимая область просмотра.